# Open URL from JSON via C# and ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have variable URL strings that are read from an external JSON block into the C# code behind.

I am then creating clickable buttons in a table which need to open a new window and launch those URLs. These are held in object's String variables.

However, I cannot find a way to make a function on the aspx side that opens a window on click and uses the URL string.

Currently I am adding a attribute to the button

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Attributes.Add("onClick", "OpenURL()");
bCell.Controls.Add(b);
```

With this I can open a window, but I can't seem to get the URL I deserialized from the JSON string over to the OpenURL()

```
function OpenURL(url) {var x = window.open(url, 'mynewwin');
```

function on the front end.

Since the url varies, I cannot hard code it anywhere.

All of the buttons, rows, and cells are generated dynamically from the JSON strings. So no hard coding can happen on these. 
//First time poster. Tried to look for solutions but failed

Comment: check if you can encode the url before passing it to window.open. You can check the details here - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

Comment: I am not having trouble with the URL encoding. I cannot find a way to send the URL to the .aspx page at all without hard coding the value directly into the "OpenURL()" method. Example: I would like to do "OpenURL(var)", but it reads it literally. So I would then have to do "OpenURL(www.google.com)", which defeats the purpose of the variable URLs. Sorry if I am asking the question poorly.

Comment: Did you try "OpenURL("+var+")" or you can also use browser storages: local storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what the url is at the time you're creating the button, you can do:

```
Button b = new Button();
var url = "some url";
b.Attributes.Add("onClick", string.Format("OpenURL({0})",url));
bCell.Controls.Add(b);
```

If you don't know the url until after the page is loaded, you can store it in a variable on the page and retrieve it when you click the link.

```
<script>
    var url;

    //have whatever you use to set the url call this function
    function setUrl(inputUrl){
        url = inputUrl; 
    }

    function OpenURL(){
        var x = window.open(url,'some window');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you this was helpful. It did not occur to me to use a replace string in this fashion.